# Factory for helper classes with static methods?

Tags: java, oop, architecture, factory-pattern

I have a couple of helper classes (`? extends HelperBase`) which only have public static methods. I would like to have something similar to what a factory is (with singleton support), but as there is no need for an instance, I am unsure which way to go best.

In the end, I would like to have something like:

```
enum HELPER_TYPE {
    Type_A
}

abstract class HelperBase {
    abstract void do();

    static HelperBase getHelper(HELPER_TYPE type) {
    // ...
    }
}

class Helper1 extends HelperBase {
    static void doImpl() {
    // ... impl here
    }

    void do() {
        doImpl();
    }
}

// ... and then:

HelperBase helper = HelperBase.getHelper(HELPER_TYPE.Type_A);
helper.do();
```

Is there a better way ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: So you just want to call `static` method of a particular `HelperBase` subclass?

Comment: @Rohit Jain, yes. But I would like to have the helpers implement a marker interface, or extend an abstract base class.

Comment: Why would you like that?

Comment: @Rohit Jain, for not having to if-else each place/time I need to call certain methods which each helper should implement.

Comment: You said, your classes just have `static` methods right? There is no polymorphism here. What kind of `if-else` condition do you have. We need some more code now. Or may be, a concrete problem statement.

Comment: It is a little bit weird as you actually specify what exacly you want in `HelperBase helper = HelperBase.getHelper(HELPER_TYPE.Type_A);`. Why cannot you just write `HelperBase helper = new Helper1();` ? If you want abstraction, just use a factory...

Answer (score 1):

```
enum HELPER_TYPE implements IHelper{
    Type_A{
        @Override
        public void doSomething(){

        }
    },
    Type_B{
       @Override
       public void doSomething(){
       }
    }
}

interface IHelper{
    public void doSomething();
}
```

How about having an interface with required methods and having `enum` implement that?

Now you have polymorphic behavior among all helpers implementing `IHelper` interface.

So you can call them like `HELPER_TYPE.Type_A.doSomething()`